# plot multiple discrete graphs on the same figure

Tags: matlab

having troubles using 3 stem function on the same figure.
my code (only for the plot part) is:

```
figure(1)
stem(s,'*');
hold
stem (v,'kx');
hold
stem(x,'color',([0 0.5 0]));
title('the discrete signals');
xlabel('n');
ylabel('signal value');
legend('s[n]','v[n]','x[n]');
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: what is the trouble?

Comment: it only plotting the first or two first graphs. never all of them

Comment: there can be many reasons for that. Try putting hold on after the last stem

Comment: It's better to use `hold on` and `hold off`, so the intent is clear. For for your own sake and others reading the code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"hold" toggles the hold state between on and off.

So the first instance toggle "hold on" the second "hold off", so you should only see the last plot.